# I am need select a option at the tk_menuOption and after invoke um event

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

What I want is for it to fire the event bind to each choice made.

So I will not use a button to call any event.

This is my The doubt:

```
set choice [list \
{News} \
{Nature} \
{City} \
{Food} \
{People} \
{Anime} \
{Tecnology} \
{Objects} \
{Others}]

tk_optionMenu . chose {*}$choice

bind . <1> { 
    clipboard clear
    clipboard append [%W cget -text]
    bell
    # Procedure to be invoke, this bellow:
    load
}
   
proc load { } {
   # Code here!
   tk_messageBox -message "You picked the option: $chose"
}
```

How to can I have some a event bind for tk_optionMenu, since that I can change first each option so to after do call procedure.

As in `bind . <1>`, there is no time to choose. Then, it is triggered by clicking on `tk_menuOption`.

I even tried to switch to other properties of the `bind` itself, but I didn't get the expected result.

I think something is missing to make it work as proposed in the question. I think it must be a stopwatch, which waits a few milliseconds before calling the event. This is what I imagine.

Comment: I really wouldn't advise calling a procedure `load` as there's a builtin command with the same name (that loads dynamic libraries). It'll work… until it doesn't and things blow up in a weird and wonderful way. I hit pretty much exactly this long ago when I called an image for an icon `open` and then wondered why my code couldn't open any files…

Comment: @DonalFellows Thanks for your time. Find this out because you and [SchelteBron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638451/9485117) are warning me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though we already have the answers as good solutions that this problem addresses.

Before I even received the answer, everyone found this link - https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/tk_optionMenu

**The description of the "*snippet*" in the link is as follows:**

```
tk_optionMenu $w varName a b c d 
for {set i 0} {$i < [[$w cget -menu] index end]} {incr i} {
    [$w cget -menu] entryconfig $i -command $cmd 
}
```

That was the discovery of the answer to solve my problem. So, I want to share with friends:

## My Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
# \
exec wish "$0" "$@"

package require Tk

. configure -width 300 -height 200

set choice [list \
{News} \
{Nature} \
{City} \
{Food} \
{People} \
{Anime} \
{Tecnology} \
{Objects} \
{Others} ]

tk_optionMenu .foo chose {*}$choice

for {set i 0} {$i < [[.foo cget -menu] index end]} {incr i} {
    [.foo cget -menu] entryconfig $i -command {load;bell}
}
   
proc load { } {
global chose
    # Code here!
    tk_messageBox -message "You picked the option: $chose"
}

pack .foo -side left -fill both -expand 1
.foo config -indicatoron 0 -relief flat -justify center -bg white
```

## Print:

[image]

But, the answers given by them .. [Schelte Bron](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67638451/9485117) and [Donal Fellows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67635530/9485117), were big help. Now I learn more things that I didn't know before. Since the words `load` are embedded in Tcl, it is not a good idea to use them.

Answer (score 1):

First off, `tk_optionMenu` is just a procedure.
Here's [the source for it](https://core.tcl-lang.org/tk/file?name=library/optMenu.tcl&ci=main), but it's really quite short:

```
proc ::tk_optionMenu {w varName firstValue args} {
    upvar #0 $varName var

    if {![info exists var]} {
        set var $firstValue
    }
    menubutton $w -textvariable $varName -indicatoron 1 -menu $w.menu \
            -relief raised -highlightthickness 1 -anchor c \
            -direction flush
    menu $w.menu -tearoff 0
    $w.menu add radiobutton -label $firstValue -variable $varName
    foreach i $args {
        $w.menu add radiobutton -label $i -variable $varName
    }
    return $w.menu
}
```

If it doesn't do what you want, just take the code and modify it.

Secondly, events on menus are *really* tricky! In particular, if you are on Windows or macOS then many standard events are not delivered at all due to the way that their native menuing system works. Instead, you get [two possible, useful callbacks](https://www.tcl-lang.org/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/menu.htm):

1. The `-command` callback on the menu items; this is supported by most of the menu items, especially including all the ones which end an interaction session with the menu (such as `command` items and `radiobutton` items).
2. The `-postcommand` callback on the overall menu which is called when the menu is posted to the screen, giving you an opportunity to alter the contents of the menu dynamically (if you need it).

If what you want can't be done with those, it probably shouldn't be done with a menu in the first place as the interaction pattern with menus is pretty strongly fixed. A `listbox` might be more suitable? Or something custom (you often can do those with a `text` or `canvas`; no C required).

Comment: There are additional bits and pieces to do with tearoffs. Don't use them. Torn-off menus have gone _massively_ out of fashion for GUIs, and with good reason: they were hard to use (as a user) in all toolkits that had them.

Answer (score 1):

While the tk_menuOption does not provide a binding for when an option is selected, it has an associated variable. So you can put a trace on that variable and do whatever you want in the handler:

```
trace add variable chose write {apply {{name arg op} {
    upvar 1 $name var
    clipboard clear
    clipboard append $var
    bell
    # Procedure to be invoked
    load
}}}
```

**Note**: It is not a good idea to overwrite built-in commands, like `load`. It is likely to break a lot of things.

Comment: There are no reserved words in Tcl. You are allowed to use any name for your procs. But library functions expect various commands to work in a certain way. The `load` command is called to load a binary extension. If your replacement `load` command does have that effect, then loading binary extensions will be broken.

Comment: If your program doesn't need to load any binary extensions, then replacing the `load` command will not have any immediate negative impact. However, if you later extend your program, you may not remember that you have replaced the `load` command and wonder why you get strange errors.

Comment: Thank you again for the good explanation on the subject. It's living and seizeing, always. =)